# Want to confirm that I got the right answer to an "iterated integrals" question.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, multiple-integral

> For positive real numbers $R$ and $r$, let 
>   $$E(R, r) = \{\frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}{R^2} + \frac{x_4^2}{r^2}\leq 1\}$$
>   Using an iterated integral, calculate the volume of $E(R,r)$.

I am not sure if I did this right since I did not use an *iterated* integral:
\begin{align}
\int_{-r}^{r}R^2(1 - \frac{x_4^2}{r^2})\;dx_4 &= R^2(x_4 - \frac{x_4^3}{3r^2})\Big|^r_{-r} \\
&=2R^2(r - r / 3) \\
&= \frac{4R^2r}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: That looks wrong. I think you would expect the volume to be proportional to $R^3r$. You could introduce new coordinates $y_1=x_1/R$, $y_2=x_2/R$, $y_3=x_3/R$ and $y_4=x_4/r$. You will get that the volume is $R^3r$ (the functional determinant) times the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @mickep Would you mind going into more detail as to your method?  I get the *idea* but do not see how to put that idea onto paper.  Thanks!

Comment: The change of variables or the calculation of the volume of the unit ball? For the latter, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball).

Comment: @mickep Okay, so I get the derivation of the unit ball.  But your reasoning seems to be "just scale up by $R^3r$."  How do you *rigorously* justify such a calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the change of coordinates suggested in the comment $E(R,r)$ is transformed into the unit ball $$D:y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2\leq 1$$ in $\mathbb R^4$. According to the [rule for changing coordinates in multiple integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables),
$$
\text{vol}\,(E(R,r))=\int_{E(R,r)}1\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4=
\int_D \frac{d\mathbf x}{d\mathbf y}\,dy_1\,dy_2\,dy_3\,dy_4
$$
where
$$
\frac{d\mathbf x}{d\mathbf y}
$$
is the [Jacobian matrix determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), i.e. the determinant of the matrix consisting of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_k}$ in place $(j,k)$. In this case, the Jacobian matrix is diagonal, with diagonal entries $R$, $R$, $R$ and $r$. Thus
$$
\frac{d\mathbf x}{d\mathbf y}=R^3r,
$$
and
$$
\text{vol}\,(E(R,r))=\int_D R^3r\,dy_1\,dy_2\,dy_3\,dy_4=R^3r\,\text{vol}\,(D).
$$
Now, you are back on safe ground, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for your help!